# How to sort elements in an array or just print them sorted?

Tags: groovy, aws-cli

I wrote the following Groovy code which returns an array of CIDR blocks in use throughout all 3 AWS regions we use, the results are populated to a Jenkins extended parameter:

```
def regions = ['us-west-2', 'us-east-1', 'eu-west-1']
        def output = []
        regions.each { region ->
            def p = ['/usr/local/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs', '--region', region].execute() | 'grep -w CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,\\|\\{\\|\\\\["'].execute() | 'uniq'.execute()
            p.waitFor()
            p.text.eachLine { line ->
                output << line
            }
        }
        output.each {
            println it
        }
```

The output of the code looks like so:

```
172.31.0.0/16
172.56.0.0/16
172.55.0.0/16
172.64.0.0/16
172.52.0.0/16
```

I would like to sort the output in a numeric way, can it be done?

Edit #1:

If I use ".sort()" I get the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.sort() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: drop(int), tr(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence), wait(), toSet(), size(), size()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.sort() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: drop(int), tr(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence), wait(), toSet(), size(), size()
    at populate_parameter_with_used_cidrs$_run_closure2.doCall(populate_parameter_with_used_cidrs.groovy:15)
    at populate_parameter_with_used_cidrs.run(populate_parameter_with_used_cidrs.groovy:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general hints to your code first:

`p.waitFor()` is not necessary if you do `p.text`, as this waits for the process to finish first anyway.

To get a list of `String`s for the lines of a multi-line `String`, you can simply use `readLines()`.

To transform one list into another list you can use `collect()` or `collectMany()`.

This would boil down your code to

```
def regions = ['us-west-2', 'us-east-1', 'eu-west-1']
def output = regions.collectMany { ['/usr/local/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs', '--region', it].execute() | 'grep -w CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,\\|\\{\\|\\\\["'].execute() | 'uniq'.execute().text.readLines() }
output.each { println it }
```

And to get the number-aware sorting, you add to that

```
output = output.sort { a, b ->
    def aparts = a.split('[./]').collect { it as short }
    def bparts = b.split('[./]').collect { it as short }
    (0..4).collect { aparts[it] <=> bparts[it] }.find() ?: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `.sort()`?

```
def list = ['172.31.0.0/16', '172.56.0.0/16', '172.55.0.0/16', '172.64.0.0/16', '172.52.0.0/16']
println list.sort()
```

Comment: It's not a list though, but an array... please check Edit #1 in my question, thanks.

Comment: It is not an array, but a list. In Groovy `[...]` defines a list or map, not an array, if you need it as array, you need to use `as String[]` or similar. But this answer will only work as long as the octets have the same length, it just does a string comparison. so if you add e. g. `'172.111.0.0/16'` to your input, it will be at first position, not at last, if you add `'72.31.0.0/16'` to your input, it will be at last position, not first, and thus is not sorted numerically.

Answer (score 0):

As an option: to sort and remove duplicates

```
(output as SortedSet).each {
            println it
        }
```

Comment: I need the result to be an array otherwise the results won't show up in the drop down menu of the extended parameter in Jenkins..

Comment: This will not sort numerically but only with `String` comparison like Raos answer too.